# python multiprocessing why much slower

Tags: python, multiprocessing

For a map task from a list src_list to dest_list, len(src_list) is of the level of thousands:

```
def my_func(elem):
    # some complex work, for example a minimizing task
    return new_elem

dest_list[i] = my_func(src_list[i])
```

I use multiprocessing.Pool

```
pool = Pool(4)
# took 543 seconds
dest_list = list(pool.map(my_func, src_list, chunksize=len(src_list)/8))

# took 514 seconds
dest_list = list(pool.map(my_func, src_list, chunksize=4))

# took 167 seconds
dest_list = [my_func(elem) for elem in src_list]
```

I am confused. Can someone explain why the multiprocessing version runs even slower?

And I wonder what are the considerations to the choice of chunksize and the choice between 
multi-threads and multi-processes, especially for my problem. Also, currently, I measure time
by sum all time spent in the my_func method because directly using

```
t = time.time()
dest_list = pool.map...
print time.time() - t
```

doesn't work. However, in [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), the document says map() *blocks until the result is ready*, it seems different to my result. Is there another way rather than simply sum the time? I have tried *pool.close()* with *pool.join()* which does not work.

src_list is of length around 2000. time.time()-t doesn't work because it does not sum up all the time spent in my_func in pool.map. And strange thing happended when I used timeit.

```
def wrap_func(src_list):
    pool = Pool(4)
    dest_list = list(pool.map(my_func, src_list, chunksize=4))

print timeit("wrap_func(src_list)", setup="import ...")
```

It ran into

```
OS Error Cannot allocate memory
```

guess I have used timeit in a wrong way...

I use python 2.7.6 under Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks!

Comment: How large is `src_list`? How large are the data structures inside of it?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean when say that using `t = time.time() ; print `time.time() = t` doesn't work. What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Regarding time measurement, you could use the timeit module.

Comment: timeit doesn't work for my case, or I have used it wrongly. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 6):

Multiprocessing requires overhead to pass the data between processes because processes do not share memory. Any object passed between processes must be pickled (*represented* as a string) and depickled. This includes objects passed to the function in you list `src_list` and any object returned to `dest_list`. This takes time. To illustrate this you might try timing the following function in a single process and in parallel.

```
def NothingButAPickle(elem):
    return elem
```

If you loop over your `src_list` in a single process this should be extremely fast because Python only has to make one copy of each object in the list in memory. If instead you call this function in parallel with the multiprocessing package it has to (1) pickle each object to send it from the main process to a subprocess as a string (2) depickle each object in the subprocess to go from a string representation to an object in memory (3) pickle the object to return it to the main process represented as a string, and then (4) depickle the object to represent it in memory in the main process. Without seeing your data or the actual function, this overhead cost typically only exceeds the multiprocessing gains if the objects you are passing are extremely large and/or the function is actually not that computationally intensive.

Comment: Get your point, Michael. Does this imply that I should use multi-thread? And still, I think that my_func requires far more time than extra picking overheads, so multi-processing should't work so much slower.

Comment: Because multithreading in python is effectively limited to one core for cpu bound tasks, it will be slower. See information on the GIL.

Comment: @fetcher How big is the list in memory/ how big is each object in the list? How long does a single call to the function take in a single process? Max is right, mutltithreading still only uses a single core. It will speed up a non-CPU bound task like web scraping, because it does not wait for a response from the site before asking for another link from another site. But multithreading only uses a single process and when that process is busy using the CPU it is busy using the CPU.

Comment: It turns out that I have stored too much in a single object in src_list. I try to reduce the size of objects in src_list. Now it ran faster (320 seconds), but still slower than the straightforward method. So what's the best strategy in my case to run in parallel? Should I split the src_list beforehand and run each piece in separate processes? Doesn't the chunksize option do the same thing?